# can not delete file in java after calling delete function

Tags: java

i tried to delete a specific file using this method :

```
File file = new File("C:\Users\Lenovo\exercises\exo\file.csv");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
        System.out.println("file is succefully deleted");
    } else {
        System.out.println("file not exist");
    }
```

to be sure that the delete function is executed , i added System.out.println
Now this message "file is succefully deleted" is displayed correctly but when i checked the folder , the file still exist ! why ? there is any error in my code ?

Comment: File permissions may not allow you to delete it. The delete method returns a boolean which indicates whether the deletion was successful. You should, at the very least, check that return value.

Comment: @Tom using an older library is not necessarily an error. Not every project uses the latest Java release.

Comment: Why are you deleting it at all? If this is a prelude to creating a new one with `FileOutputStream` or `FileReader`, just let them overwrite it: no need to keep a dog and bark yourself.

Comment: I agree with @Tom here. There is no reason whatsoever to stick to `File` in 2017. Unless you are still stuck with Java 6 which has now been EOLed for more than 10 _years_.

Comment: @Michael thank you so much , I checked the return value , it was false

Comment: @Tom No, there is no error in the code. There is a usage with which you disagree. It isn't the same thing, by a country mile.

Comment: seen... anyway thank you @Tom